# How to download packages from a repository that is not in sources.list

Tags: apt

I'm remastering a CD for Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid), but that is not the version I'm running and I don't want to add its repositories in souces.list.

Is there a way to download the latest versions of its packages from the repository without editing sources.list?

Answer (score 2):

Before starting: **You really shouldn't remaster Lucid**. It's more than 3 years old, will cease support in April 2014 and most of the common packages doesn't receive updates. Remaster 12.04 if you must, but don't use Lucid. That said, my instructions may not work for anything before Precise.

---

> Is there a way to download the latest versions of its packages from the repository without editing sources.list?

You can ask apt-get to use another sources.list file. Just add `-o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/some/file` to the `apt-get` call. This may work for aptitude too.

Comment: I got `E: Release 'lucid' for 'ubuntu-keyring' was not found`. Alright, missing update - I then tried to use apt-get update with `-o Dir::State::Lists` to use an alternate directory, but when I use that the `Dir::Etc::SourceList` gets ignored and apt-get downloads everything from my sources.list.

Comment: @Penz as I said in my first paragraph, it may not work for anything before precise. I'm able to do what you asked with the method above, which is using another sources.list. Whatever happens with the packages is inherently to the fact that you are using Lucid.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention something: even though I want to remaster Lucid, I'm running Debian Jessie (testing), which has apt-get version 0.9.12.1.